# How to update the summation of column in table without page refreshing using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

```
include "config.php";
$output = "";

//deleting part
if(isset($_POST["id"])) {
    foreach($_POST["id"] as $id) {
        $delete = "DELETE FROM sat WHERE id = '".$id."'"; 
        mysqli_query($connection, $delete);
    }
}

//viewing part
$output .= "<table>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    $numberof = $numberof + 1;
    $totalcost = $totalcost + $row['third'];

    $output .= '<tr>
                <td>' .$numberof. '</td>
                <td>' .$row['first']. '</td>
                <td>' .$row['second']. '</td>
                <td>' .$row['third']. '</td>
                </tr>';
}
$output .= "<tr>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>$totalcost.00</td>
            </tr>
            </table>";
```

This is my php page where both viewing and deleting process takes place in one php file. The process begins by getting the request from the user to delete any data from the row. The problem is that I need to refresh the page in order to get the actual summation value of "column = third". Otherwise it will be showing the previous summation value. Fyi, the delete process will be depending on the checkbox request. Code below shows the ajax part:

```
$("#confirmCB").on("click", function () {
        if(confirm("Are you confirm with the selection?")) {
            var id = [];

            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
                id[i] = $(this).val();
            });
            if(id.length === 0) {
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data:{id:id},
                    success:function() 
                    {
                        for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++) {
                            $('tr#'+id[i]+'').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
                            $('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
}
        else {
            return false;
        }

});
```

Comment: Have you heard of AJAX? It's the answer to most questions of the format "How can I do X without refreshing the page".

Comment: and heave you heard about GRIDs? most of them have a functionality like header/footer with sums, avgs, etc. out of the box.

Comment: i did try the ajax. can you help me show the logic?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show how you were trying to do this with AJAX? That seems to be more of what the question is about and it's rather broad without any of that to go on.

Comment: yea sure. try to see the code